# run python script with arguments on compute engine using cloud composer

Tags: airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am new to GCP and I want to setup a cloud composer and my flow looks like file_in_bucket>turn_on_compute_engine_instance>run_python_script_in_compute_engine>tunr_off_compute_engine. I have seen few resources on how to use SSHoperator to run script in compute engine when script is stored in compute engine but can we store script in DAG/ and use the script to run on different VM. The reason is because we have multiple VM and when we update a script it becomes more complex because we need to update the script on more than 30 compute engine.

Comment: Could you please break up/restructure the question? It's quite hard to understand now what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I have 30 compute engines in my project and I have to execute a python script during composer DAG on one compute engine, I was confused whether I need to use bashoperator or sshoperator.